# Primed variables with subscript horizontal subcript spacing

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subscripts

Is there a way to make the prime symbol of the variable align horizontally with the subscript?

If I do `$R\prime_0$` the `0` is too far from the `R`, I want it to be the same distance as if I do `$R_0$`. If I try to put the prime as a superscript, the prime symbol is too small.

Thanks!

Comment: Write either `$R^{\prime}_0$` or, if the prime symbol really needs to be bigger, `$R^{\textstyle\prime}_0$`

Comment: Are you talking about `R^\prime_0`?

Answer (score 3):

The "prime" character was designed (by DEK) in TeX very special. The input symbol `'` is set as math-active and it is defined by plain TeX (and in other formats too) like `^\prime` (roughly speaking). Because superscript uses smaller font, the base prime character (printed directly by `\prime`) is designed somewhat bigger and it is never used in normal situations. The optimal size is only in superscript.

Why do you use complicated `$R\prime_0$` instead of simple `$R'_0$`?

TeXbook says at page 130:

> The control sequence `\prime` stands for the symbol *(printed here)*, which is used mostly in superscripts. In fact this symbol is so big as it stands that you would **never want to use it** except in subscript or superscript, where it occurs in a smaller size.
>
> Since single and double primes occur rather frequently, plain TeX provides a convenient abbreviation: You can simply type `'` instead `^\prime` and `''` instead `^{\prime\prime}`, and so on.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer the question. It seems better-suited as a comment.

Comment: This is answer because it explains the background of the mistake done by OP and suggests the solution: `R'_0`.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to write either `R^{\prime}_0` (alias: `R'_0`) or `R^{\textstyle\prime}_0`. The latter looks ghastly, though, doesn't it?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$R^{\prime}_0 \quad  R'_0\quad R^{\textstyle\prime}_0$
\end{document}
```